# Linq outer joins

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I need help to convert the following query to Linq

```
SELECT c.Code, c.Name
from tblCodes as c
where c.code not in 
    (select Code from npConsultant where ConsultantName = 'X')
    and c.Code < 'AA.0000'
```

When I try in Linqpad it doesn't seem to understand the into or defaultifempty. Maybe these are inproper methods for what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is use the "let" keyword and generate a sub-query that supports your conditional set for the main entity.

```
var Objlist= from u in tblCodes 
             let ces = from ce in npConsultant 
             select ce.code 
             where !ces.Contains(u.code)
             select u;
```

Comment: Tried this version and it will execute but returns no results even though the sql query from above does return 64 rows.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
var query =    
from c in Customers    
where !(from n in npConsultant
    where n.ConsultantName='X'    
        select n.Code)    
       .Contains(c.Code)    
    && c.Code < 'AA.0000'
select c.Code, c.Name;
```

I just do not get how Code can be less than 'AA.0000' ....

Comment: Tried the above in LINQPAD and it tells me the variables are too large for the fields even though they are less then the table definitions